# How to use a rule and its derivative on an equation?

Tags: rule

I generated a very simple rule that is of the type

```
{a[0] -> 0,  a[1] -> 0,  a[2] -> 8/3*pi}
```

And I want to impose this set of rules on an equation. The problem is that in this equation there are some derived terms like `a'[0]`. How can I use the rule directly by imposing its derivative where needed as well?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica S.E. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You can do this also in the same way i.e. `{a[0] -> 0,  a[1] -> 0,  a[2] -> 8/3*pi, a'[0]->value}`

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Given rules like `{a[0] -> 0,  a[1] -> 0,  a[2] -> 8/3*Pi}` you cannot take their derivative since everything is constant.

An example for which derivatives can be taken.

```
eqn = {a''[x] + 4 a[x] == 0, a[0] == 1, a'[0] == 4};
```

Rule:

```
sol = DSolve[eqn, a[x], x][[1]]

(* {a[x] -> Cos[2 x] + 2 Sin[2 x]} *)
```

Derivatives:

```
der = NestList[D[#, x] &, sol, 2] // Flatten

(* {a[x] -> Cos[2 x] + 2 Sin[2 x], 
 a'[x] -> 4 Cos[2 x] - 2 Sin[2 x], a''[x] -> -4 Cos[2 x] - 
   8 Sin[2 x]} *)
```

Initial conditions:

```
ic = Most@der /. x -> 0

(* {a[0] -> 1, a'[0] -> 4} *)
```

Verification,

```
eqn /. der /. ic // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set derivatives of constants to zero you can write e.g.:

```
2 a[0] + 3 a[1]' + 4 a[2]'' /. {Derivative[_][_] -> 0}
(* 2 a[0] *)
```

However, if the derivatives have some values that you want to replace, you can write:

```
drule = {a[0]' -> 11, a[1]' -> 22, a[2]' -> 33};
2 a[0] + 3 a[1]' + 4 a[2]' /. drule
(* 198 + 2 a[0] *)
```